# Why sometimes Observer LiveData show log more than once?

Tags: android-livedata, android-viewmodel

In Fragment get my viewModel from ViewModelProvider:

```
val todoViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
        this, TodoViewModel.Factory(
            requireNotNull(this.activity).application)).get(TodoViewModel::class.java)
```

This is ViewModel:

```
class TodoViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
var todoRepository: TodoRepository? = null

init {
    todoRepository = TodoRepository(application)

}

fun allTodosBefor() = todoRepository?.allTodosBefor()!!

fun insertTodo(todo: TodoEntity): LiveData<Long> {
    val id = MutableLiveData<Long>()
    viewModelScope.launch {
        id.value = todoRepository?.insertTodo(todo)
    }
    return id
}

fun updateTodo(todo: TodoEntity) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        todoRepository?.updateTodo(todo)
    }
 }
}
```

Then want to get all Data from viewModel:

```
private fun allTodosBefor(todoViewModel: TodoViewModel, todoAdapter: TodoAdapter) {
    todoViewModel.allTodosBefor().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        it?.let {
            Log.d(TAG, "allTodosBefor: ${it.size}")
            todoAdapter.data = it
        }
    })
}
```

but in log sometimes get more than once the size of my LiveData

Comment: Probably you should add `TodoViewModel` class and maybe `TodoViewModel.Factory`. I think you call `allData()` twice in some cases, for instance, in loading state and finish state. Are `todoViewModel` and `viewModel` the same?

Comment: Yeah, they are the same.
But this is only `allData()` call in my fragment

Comment: I also got this problem in another application. Then unsubscribed from ViewModel, but that was not a solution.

Comment: I searched like "android viewmodel observe multiple times". Then tested several solutions and found a mistake in my code.

Comment: Good luck, sir!

Comment: Show your viewModel code, as well as what is `allData()`.

Comment: Done, please check again.

Comment: You're observing Livedata exposed from a Room DB directly from a Fragment, Livedata is a value holder, and will emit the last value to new subscribers. You're probably calling this from the onViewCreated (subscribing). When your fragment's view is created (or recreated) you get the last value + the new value coming from the DB (which may be the same). It's just a theory but it certainly looks like that.